# systemverilog : tri0 vs pulldown - is there any difference?

Tags: system-verilog, tri-state-logic

Is there meant to be any functional difference between making a wire "tri0" vs applying a "pulldown" component to the wire?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, declaring a signal to be `tri0` is functionally equivalent to declaring that signal as a `wire` and connecting the signal to a `pulldown`.

There is an exception when you pass that signal through a port, and make a connection to a signal with a dissimilar net type (See section *23.3.3.7 Port connections with dissimilar net types (net and port collapsing)* in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM). For that reason, I recommend that you use the pulldown to avoid confusion.